# how to memoize function in rust

Tags: rust

```
fn foo(num: usize, memory: HashMap<usize, usize>) -> usize {
    if memory.contains_key(&num) {return memory[&num];}
    // other code
}
```

I have a lot of functions that need memoization. I know above code works, but I don't want to create a lot of variables unrelated to the function. What is the best practice for memoizing functions in Rust?

For example in python you can to that.

```
@cache
def foo()
```

Comment: There is the [`memoize`](https://crates.io/crates/memoize) crate, which works similarly to your Python.

Comment: Also, instead of `contains_key()` then indexing (two lookups), do `if let Some(cached) = memory.get(&num) { return num; }`.

Comment: Of course that should be `return *cached;` instead of `return num;` in @ChayimFriedman's comment

Comment: when you try to this method you will encounter with "as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable" Error.  When you try to insert the result to the HashMap.

Comment: @PYigit [It works fine in simple cases](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4e2407bb4654e4518f19ec9e2f51a025), but maybe in more complex cases you will encounter NLL problem case #3.